# Set UITabBarController index upon dismissing modal view

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with 2 tabs, One tab calls:

```
[self.documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

which brings up a full image view (can't seem to change it from non full screen), anyways, when I tap done it resets my tab bar to the first index.

I know the reason why because I declared:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setSelectedViewController:activeDL];
}
```

This is the view I want my tab bar to load, placing that anywhere else crashes the app.

Main question: How can I have my tab bar to load initial view, but stay on the view selected from the modal view?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I narrowed it down and possibly fixed my issue.

In both my tab bar view controllers I have a done button to dismiss the tab bar from either view. Inside that done button function I called:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:0];
}];
```

This allows the tab bar when opened or re-opened to start off at that first view. But if I'm in the view for preview and I close the preview, it will remain in that view it left.

Hope this helps somebody and if I find an error within it I will edit.